# display records periodically in minimongo to client

Tags: meteor

I have a collection called `books`

In my subscription I'm sending 5 records to client,

Now I want to display a single record to client for every 3 minutes

I've tried like this

```
on the helper I'm returning

Template.book.helpers({
    'book':function(){
          var books=Books.find({});
          books.forEach(function(book){
          setTimeout(function(){
               Session.set("currentBookId",book._id);
          },3*60*1000);
         });
         return Books.find({_id:Session.get("curentBookId")}); 
      }
})
```

This is displaying the last record
I know this will not work, can anybody suggest me a correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your helpers should not have have [side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)). A helper's job is to reactively read and/or translate data, not to change state. You should use a `setInterval` outside of the helper to randomly choose a new book. Here's a working solution:

```js
var THREE_MINUTES = 3 * 60 * 1000;

var chooseRandomBook = function() {
  // fetch all of the published books
  var books = Books.find().fetch();

  // if there is only one book, just keep it and return
  if (books.length === 1)
    return Session.set('currentBookId', books[0]._id);

  // extract an array of book ids which don't contain the current book id
  var bookIds = _.chain(books)
    .pluck('_id')
    .without(Session.get('currentBookId'))
    .value();

  // choose a random id from the array
  var bookId = Random.choice(bookIds);

  // set the currentBookId to our random choice
  Session.set('currentBookId', bookId);
};

Template.book.helpers({
  book: function() {
    return Books.findOne(Session.get('currentBookId'));
  }
});

Template.book.created = function() {
  // choose a random book every three minutes, store the handle for cleanup
  this.handle = Meteor.setInterval(chooseRandomBook, THREE_MINUTES);
};

Template.book.destroyed = function() {
  // stop choosing books when we are done with this template
  Meteor.clearInterval(this.handle);
};
```

Comment: Hi David, I don't want to repeat the the books,If we use random it will pick up the random id, how to avoid that? Thx for the help

Comment: I updated the answer - you can just remove the current id from `bookIds` before you choose a new one. The updated answer also deals with the case where there is only one book.